# Flutter map into model

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter model that contains a map of type <String, Object>, and I would like to know how it should be passed in the fromJson() function, or if the way I have it is the correct way.

EDIT: I would also like to know the form for a data of type List.

[image]

Comment: It would be better if you can include model class as snippet

Answer (score 1):

Try making it simplified and clean. Here is an example.

```
factory CartModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CartModel(
      productName: json['productName'],
      description: json['description'],
      price: json['price'],
      productId: json['productId'],
      rating: json['rating'],
      time: json['time'],
      category: json['category'],
      imageUrl: json['imgUrl'],
      type: json['type'],
      quantity: json['quantity'],
      totalPrice: json['totalPrice'],
      addonList: json['addonList'],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Function to convert `Json` to `Model`**

```
static Future<List<ListModel>> getList() async {
        final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/examle.json');
        final jsonStr = await json.decode(response);
        List<ListModel> list = json.decode(jsonStr);
    
        return list;
      }
```

> Model

import 'dart:convert';

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class ListModel {
  ListModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  int? id;
  String? name;
  
  factory ListModel.fromRawJson(String str) =>
      ListModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toJson());

  factory ListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ListModel(
        id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id == null ? null : id,
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
      };
}
```

> Json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Anand", 
  },{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Anand", 
  }
]
```